# Wrong path to CSS in subpage

Tags: php, html, css, path

You can see on the first image I have a sub-page where the location to CSS is wrong because the path to CSS looks like this:

```
http://localhost/tibiaservers_11.10.19/dbko-inferno.pl-ots/css_bootstrap/bootstrap.css
```

it should be like below

```
 http://localhost/tibiaservers_11.10.19/css_bootstrap/bootstrap.css
```

that's the links to the sub-pages which one looks like name-ots

```html
<td class="mobile_hide_180"><a class="hrefo " href="'.$web_link.strtolower($Row['ip']).'-ots/"> '.$Row['name'].'</a><span style="display:none;"><a class="IDhrefo hidden" href="'.$Row['id'].'"></a></span></td>
```

https://imgur.com/ABSmgna

https://imgur.com/hwgH6Am

and thats the code of whole ots.php file

How to deal with that problem? All others subpages loads css with right path.

```html
<?php


if(isset($_GET['postlang'])){
 include('../mysql_config.php');
 include('../config.php');
 include('../includes/functions.php');
 include('view_quick_buttons.php');
 include('view_comments.php');
 $lang = addslashes ( $_GET['postlang'] );
 if ( is_file ( '../lang/' .$lang. '.php' ) )
 {
  include '../lang/'.$lang.'.php';
  $_SESSION['lang']=$lang;
 }else{
  include '../lang/'.$default_lang.'.php';
  $_SESSION['lang']=$default_lang;
 }
}
$class['fav']="";

if(isset($_GET['ip'])){
$ZapytanieID = $mysqli -> query ( 'SELECT * FROM `list_ots` WHERE `ip` = "' .$_GET['ip']. '"' );
$Row = $ZapytanieID->fetch_assoc();
//echo $rowZ['id'];
$IP = $Row['ip'];
$ID = $Row['id'];
}




if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$SearchQuery = $mysqli -> query ( 'SELECT * FROM `list_ots` WHERE `id` = "' .$_GET['id']. '"' );
$Row = $SearchQuery -> fetch_assoc(); 
$ID = $Row['id'];
$IP = $Row['ip'];
}




if ( $SearchQuery -> num_rows == 1)
{
 
 
 if(!isset($_GET['postlang'])){
  include('pages/view_quick_buttons.php');
  include('pages/view_comments.php');
 }
 
 $vote_good = $mysqli -> query ( 'SELECT count(*) FROM `list_votes` WHERE `server`="'.$IP.'" AND `vote`="1"')->fetch_assoc(); 
 $vote_bad = $mysqli -> query ( 'SELECT count(*) FROM `list_votes` WHERE `server`="'.$IP.'" AND `vote`="2"')->fetch_assoc();

 
 /*$check_ban=$mysqli->query('SELECT count(*) FROM `list_bans` where `server`="'.$rowZ['id'].'"')->fetch_assoc();
 if($check_ban['count(*)']!=0){
  header("Location: $web_link");
  exit;
 }*/
 
 if ( $Row['status'] == 1)
 {
  $ColorStatus = 'dark_green';
  $Status = 'Online';
  $PlayersCount = $Row['players']. ' (' .$Row['rec']. ') / ' .$Row['maxplayers'];
 }else{
  $ColorStatus = 'red';
  $Status = 'Offline';
  $PlayersCount = '0 (' .$Row['rec']. ') / ' .$Row['maxplayers'];
 }

 $desc=str_replace("\n","</br>",$Row['desc']);

 if($Row['client']==-1){
  $Row['client']=$_LANG['server_info']['na'];
 }
 $uptime_temp=explode('.',number_format($Row['uptimepc'],2));
 $uptime=$uptime_temp[0];
 if($uptime_temp[1]!="00") $uptime.='.'.$uptime_temp[1];
 
echo '
<div class="status-widgets">

 <div class="row-fluid w940">

  <div class="well-header">
  <h5>'.$Row['name'].'</h5>
  </div>
 
 <div id="otswholeborder">

 
 <div class="row-fluid w940">
  <div class="span6">
   <div class="widget borderots clearfix">
    <div class="details">
     <div class="number">
      <p>'.$Row['ip'].'</p>
     </div>

     <div class="description">
      IP
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="span6">
   <div class="widget borderots clearfix">
    <div class="details">
     <div class="number">
      '.$Row['port'].'
     </div>
     <div class="description">
      PORT
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  
 

 <div class="row-fluid w940">
  <div class="span6">
   <div class="widget borderots clearfix">
    <div class="details">
     <div class="number">
      '.$PlayersCount.'
     </div>
     <div class="description">
      '.$_LANG['server_info']['players'].'
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="span6">
   <div class="widget borderots clearfix">
    <div class="details">
     <div class="number">
      '.$uptime.' %
     </div>
     <div class="description">
      '.$_LANG['server_info']['uptime'].'
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 
 

  <div class="row-fluid w940">
    <div class="span6">
   <div class="widget borderots clearfix"">
    <div class="details">
     <div class="number">
      <span class="description>"Status</span> '.$Status.'
     </div>
     <div class="description">
      Status
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="span6">
   <div class="widget borderots clearfix"">
    <div class="details">
     <div class="number">
      '.$Row['client'].'
     </div>
     <div class="description">
      '.$_LANG['server_info']['client'].'
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>


 
 </div>
</div>


<div class="row-fluid w940">
 <div class="quick-actions">
  <ul>
   ';
   if(is_logged()){
    echo'
    <li><a class="'.$class['vote_good'].'" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="'.$_LANG['server_view']['good'].'" href="?page=ots&ip='.$Row['ip'].'&action=vote_good"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></a></li>
    <li><a class="'.$class['vote_bad'].'" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="'.$_LANG['server_view']['bad'].'" href="?page=ots&ip='.$Row['ip'].'&action=vote_bad"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i></a></li>
    <li><a class="'.$class['fav'].'" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="'.$_LANG['server_view']['fav'].'" href="?page=ots&ip='.$Row['ip'].'&id='.$Row['id'].'&action=fav"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a></li>';
   }else{
    echo'
    <li><a rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="'.$_LANG['account']['for_users'].'" href="#"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a></li>
    <li><a rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="'.$_LANG['account']['for_users'].'" href="#"><i class="icon-minus"></i></a></li>
    <li><a rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="'.$_LANG['account']['for_users'].'" href="#"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a></li>

    ';

   }
  echo'
  <li><a class="btn like" style="margin-left: 30px;"> '.$vote_good['count(*)'].'</a></li>
  <li><a class="btn unlike">'.$vote_bad['count(*)'].'</a></li>

   </ul>
 </div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="row-fluid w940">
 <div class="well">


 <div class="well-content no_padding">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li class="active"><a href="#tab_desc" data-toggle="tab">'.$_LANG['server_view']['desc'].'</a></li>
     <li><a onclick="load_motd('.$Row['id'].')" href="#tab_motd" data-toggle="tab">MOTD</a></li>';
     if( $add_image_enable==1){
     echo '<li><a onclick="load_map('.$Row['id'].')" href="#tab_map" data-toggle="tab">'.$_LANG['server_view']['map'].'</a></li>';
    }
     echo '<li><a onclick="load_more_info('.$Row['id'].', \''.$_SESSION['lang'].'\')" href="#tab_info" data-toggle="tab">'.$_LANG['server_view']['info'].'</a></li>';
     if( $comments_enable==1 and $Row['comments']==1){
     echo '<li><a onclick="load_comments('.$Row['id'].')" href="#tab_comments" data-toggle="tab">'.$_LANG['server_view']['comments'].'</a></li>';
    }
   echo '</ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_desc">
    <p>'.$desc.'</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_motd">
    <div id="motd">
      <img src="img/preloader.gif">
    </div>
    </div>';
    
    if( $add_image_enable==1){
   echo '<div class="tab-pane no_padding" id="tab_map">
     <div id="map">
      <img src="img/preloader.gif">
     </div>
     </div>';
    }
    echo '<div class="tab-pane no_padding" id="tab_info">
    <div id="more_info">
     <img src="img/preloader.gif">
    </div>
    </div>'; 
   if( $comments_enable==1 and $Row['comments']==1){
    echo '<div class="tab-pane no_padding" id="tab_comments">
      <div class="well-content no_padding">
       <div id="comments">
        <img src="img/preloader.gif">
       </div>
       <div class="type_message">';
        if(is_logged()){
         echo '<form method="POST" action="?page=ots&ip='.$IP.'">
           <input maxlength="200" type="text" class="span12" name="message" placeholder="'.$_LANG['server_view']['type_here'].'">
           <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn input_button blue"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i></button>
           </form>';
        }else{
         echo '<input maxlength="200" type="text" class="span12" id="message" name="message" placeholder="'.$_LANG['server_view']['type_here'].'">
           <button rel="tooltip" title="'.$_LANG['account']['for_users'].'" type="submit" class="btn input_button blue"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i></button>';
        }          
       echo '</div>
      </div>    
     </div>';
     }    
  echo '</div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>';
//}else{
// header("Location: $web_link");
// exit;
}
?>

<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$web_link` is not defined here. How is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `link` source location in header has relative path defined to particular directory.

Here is what you have right now:

```
<link href="css_bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

but you have to define it like this:

```
<link href="/css_bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Hope it helps.